# Devexpress pie chart with zero values

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

When all the values ​​for `N` categories shown in a pie chart are zero, the chart is a circle with `N` equal sectors.

I tried using `DataFilter` as below, but then, nothing is shown at all (no chart, no legend information)

```
DataFilter dataFilter1 = new DataFilter("Amount", "System.Int32",      
    DataFilterCondition.GreaterThan, 0);
series.DataFilters.Add(dataFilter1);
```

Is there a way to show an empty (filled with white for example?) chart in such conditions?

Comment: set all lines & fills to the same (white) colour?

Comment: I guess I should do something like that.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```
 // Create an empty chart.
 ChartControl pieChart = new ChartControl();

 // Create a pie series.
 Series series1 = new Series("A Pie Series", ViewType.Pie);

 // Populate the series with points.
 series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint("No Results found", 100));

 // Add the series to the chart.
 pieChart.Series.Add(series1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to be able to show the categories, but not the chart (similar to the way `Excel` treats a pie chart with zero numbers)

Answer (score 1):

If the data you are using to build your pie graphs are already percentiles, (computed at retrieval), `pChart.Series[pData.TableName].Label = "#VALX (#VALY%)";` will do the trick

oops.. i was searching for a solution on 'Series Label (NaN)' on DataVisualization pie charts when totals are zero